# Dynamic CategoryAxis for MVC Kendo Chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Currently i have this and it works great..   What i need is for the Categories in CategoryAxis to be dynamic and not the static .Categories("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")..

I already have the value i want to put in there coming from my model,  its @item.SurveyLinearCounts.FirstOrDefault().Min   for the minimum value  and  @item.SurveyLinearCounts.FirstOrDefault().Max   for the maximum

How do i do this.?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart<AnalyzeResponseViewModel>()
                                  .Name(@item.SurveyQuestionID.ToString())
                                  .Legend(legend => legend
                                      .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Top)
                                      .Visible(true)
                                  )
                                  .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
                                      .Background("transparent")
                                  )
                                  .Series(series =>
                                  {
                                      series.Column(model => model.ResponseCount).Name("Count").Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Template("#= series.name #: #=  value #"));
                                  })
                                   .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                                      .Categories("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
                                      .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
                                  )
                              .
                              )
                                  .ValueAxis(axis => axis
                                      .Numeric()
                                      .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
                                      .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
                                  )
                                  .DataSource(ds => ds
                                      .Read(read => read.Action("GetSurveyResponseChart", "DataSource", new { item.SurveyQuestionID })))
                                  .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")))
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want. Do you just want to updated the category labels after the chart is already generated?

Comment: I want to dynamically set the labels with values from my model

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values you want are in the `item.SurveyLinearCounts` property, you should be able to do something like this:

```
.CategoryAxis(axis => axis
    .Categories(item.SurveyLinearCounts)
    .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
)
```

If there's another property in there that you'd like, you can do something like:

```
.Categories(item.SurveyLinearCounts.Select(x => x.MyProp))
```